# Create toggle button behaviour to hide or show div

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to create a button that has the following behaviour:

1) By default `List View` is showed, when the user doesn't click on anything

2) When the user clicks on the `Card View` button, `List View` is hidden, `Card View` is shown

- class of `Card View` is set to `button button-clear button-dark`
- class of `List View` is set to `button button-clear button-positive`

3) When the user clicks on the `List View` button, `Card View` is hidden, `List View` is shown

- class of `Card View` is set to `button button-clear button-positive`
- class of `List View` is set to `button button-clear button-dark`

So far I've managed to get 1) done, but I am struggling to get 2) and 3) done.

***controller.js***

```
function StatementsController($scope, $stateParams, DummyStatementsService) {
    $scope.active = true;
    $scope.toggle = function(view){
        if(view === 'list') {
            $scope.active = true;
        } else if(view === 'card') {
            $scope.active = false;
        }
    }
}
```

***statements.view.html***

```
<ion-content>
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: -1.35em" ng-controller="StatementsController">
        <div class="col">
            <button class="button button-clear button-dark" ng-click="toggle('list')">List View</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-right">
            <button class="button button-clear button-positive" ng-click="toggle('card')">Card View</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="StatementsController">
        <!-- List view -->
        <div ng-show="active">
            test 1
        </div>
        <!-- Card view -->
        <div ng-hide="active">
            test 2
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are really toggling between adding either the `button-dark` or the `button-positive` class to the buttons you can do it like this:

**Updated (x2)**

```
<ion-content> 
    <div ng-controller="StatementsController"> <!-- move the ng-controller out here -->
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: -1.35em">
            <div class="col">
                <button class="button button-clear" 
                        ng-class="{'button-positive': active, 'button-dark': !active}" 
                        ng-click="toggle('list')">List View</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-right">
                <button class="button button-clear" 
                        ng-class="{'button-positive': !active, 'button-dark': active}" 
                        ng-click="toggle('card')">Card View</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <!-- List view -->
            <div ng-show="active">
                test 1
            </div>
            <!-- Card view -->
            <div ng-hide="active">
                test 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Thanks. But how about hiding and showing the divs... that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Rather than having `ng-controller` on each div, wrap the whole thing with a single div with `ng-controller`. That way everything will be using a single scope and both the buttons and the divs you are showing/hiding will be using the same scope variable `active`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Got that working. But ng-class is returning the following error message: `Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '-' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 35 of the expression [{'button-positive': active, button-dark: !active}] starting at [-dark: !active}].`

Comment: Oh, maybe put single quotes around both class names? `{'button-positive': active, 'button-dark': !active}`

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like:

controller:

```
function StatementsController($scope, $stateParams, DummyStatementsService) {
    $scope.view = 'list';
}
```

html:

```
<ion-content controller="StatementsController">
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: -1.35em" ng->
        <div class="col">
            <button class="button button-clear button-dark" ng-click="view = 'list'">List View</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-right">
            <button class="button button-clear button-positive" ng-click="view = 'card'">Card View</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="StatementsController">
        <!-- List view -->
        <div ng-show="view === 'list">
            test 1
        </div>
        <!-- Card view -->
        <div ng-show="view === 'card'">
            test 2
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

or, using an ng-switch:

```
<div ng-switch="view">
    <!-- List view -->
    <div ng-switch-when="list">
        test 1
    </div>
    <!-- Card view -->
    <div ng-switch-when="card">
        test 2
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I just wanted to ask, where do you define `view`?

Comment: it will implicity be added to the current scope via the ng-click expressions.  However, you want a default, so I will edit my answer to show it.

Comment: @DavidA, Inside your ng-click's, a function call passing in the view type might make it a little more descriptive in what's happening rather than just assigning the type right there to a model.  exp: ng-click="swapViews('list')"

Comment: The other answer comment also pointed out you need to share a controller.  Your original code was creating 2 different controllers, one for each ng-controller statement.  I have modified my answer to show how you can move the ng-controller statement up one level to share it between the divs.

Comment: Agreed, @Chris.  Any readability changes are fair game.  My way leads to a very simple controller, but method(s) can be added if desired, particularly if more side effects are necessary.

Comment: Also, for part 3, you can use the ng-class similar to the answer by @Lex , but instead of testing 'active', test the value of 'view'.